# How to SSH into running container using docker

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins, docker

I'm trying to SSH into my running Jenkins VM which I have created with a Dockerfile.

I need to see the filestructure and copy the /var/lib/jenkins folder out to my shared folder.

How do I achieve getting into the VM?

Answer (score 4):

Do not use SSH, simply a `docker exec -it your_container bash`and then issue the commands you want. See the doc https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#exec and if you have an old verison of docker use nsenter https://github.com/jpetazzo/nsenter

Comment: In such case you have to ensure what kind of shell is installed on image using docker inspect image_name. It not always have to be bash, it might be sh or any other.

Comment: yes, it may be /bin/sh or anything else, but I suppose you know which shell is available in your container!